# How do I make Mac OS X applications use different SOCKS proxies?

Tags: macos, ssh, proxy, socks

Is there a way to make different Mac OS X applications use different SOCKS proxies?  I've had no luck using `tsocks` with Mac OS X applications like Skype, Mail, or Chrome, always segfaults.

I believe that [sshuttle](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle) could handle Mail by mapping specific IP ranges through the proxy.  Or maybe I could exclude all but the target ranges in Mac OS X's proxy settings.

IP ranges aren't well suited to proxying Skype or Chrome connections however.  I understand that a peer-to-peer application like Skype might require a more complete solution, but Chrome should survive tsocks style library replacement nicely.

I could perhaps run multiple FireFoxes simultaneously with different proxy configurations, well that already happens with Tor, but It'd be lovely to find a broader solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need a browser solution, Chrome or Firefox will work. Use proxyswitchy for Chrome or foxyproxy for firefox and you can even use multiple proxies/direct connection based on domain name regex matches.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to "encapsulate" a new process to use a SOCKS proxy you want so the process will not know that you are using proxy - a tool to do it is [tsocks](http://tsocks.sourceforge.net/). It'll also works with software that does not provide proxy configuration.

Comment: I've never seen `tsocks` actually work on OS X.